# codeigniter question global variables

Tags: codeigniter

My system uses DHCP to retrieve ipaddress  in configfile if i set my_system_ipaddress/codeigniter others cannot access my site if ip is changed.what is the solution for that

Comment: Get a fixed IP!!! Next time try writing in English, please!

Comment: I think I kind of understand. I think what you might be looking for is a service like DynDNS, which gives you a DNS name that maps to your IP address and updates that mapping whenever your IP changes. Am I on the right track there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on an intranet, fix your IP, or ask your sysadmin that configure the DHCP server to give you a fixed address.
If you plan to work on a public net, you need to work with a domain name, that is what you will use in your config files.
It's not clear if, when you say DHCP it's from your ISP or you local Lan.